# Should I steer clear of a moped 17 years old only 50 miles on the clock

Tags: engine, wheels

I think I'm about to purchase a super clean moped that's 17 years old and is said to run "perfect". It comes with the promis of an MOT if I buy. It does look mint - V5 in owners name but he hasn't had it long and and isnt forthcoming wit much info - You have to ask the questions!! Presuming it really does run "perfect" are there other issues I should be concerned about. Square wheels I will take a chance on.
 Last chance to buy tomorrow so any any quick half hearted opinion welcome. Thanks in advance....

Comment: What country are you in? In the UK the obvious thing to check would be the DVLA records. If it is taxed it will have an MOT and that will have a recorded mileage (recorded by the MOT tester, not the owner) which will be a partial check the mileage hasn't been "clocked". If it is untaxed it should have a SORN (statutory off-road notice). If not you will be in for some serious hassle it you want to retax it! But "last chance to buy tomorrow" is a big red flag IMO - and you won't have time to do those DVLA checks. If it's been unused for 17 years, another week isn't going to hurt anybody much!

Comment: @alephzero   Hi, yes I'm in the UK. Reason for the rush is that it's an auction ending Wenesday. I believe it;s not clocked as it really is in mint condition and it;s the sort of thing that is purchaesd by people with boats and campers (as it's so small)  I dont think it;s uncommon for these to bought and never properly used.  Interesting what you say about sorn. He's recently come into possession with the moped and it's in his name.  Would it really be a problem if I could prove I'm the new owner?  My question was really a technical 1 but this is aan good point.

Comment: I think the problem would be proving the current "owner" is genuine, if there is no DVLA record trail. Obviously the regulations have changed in 17 years but presumably *somebody* must have been the registered keeper at one time. Note, for vehicle tax purposes the "owner" and the "registered keeper" are not necessarily the same person. A registration document doesn't prove *ownership.* If nobody is the registered keeper, I don't know what the procedure would be - but you may have to pay a fee to re-register it before you can tax it, for example.

Comment: @alephzero  Although recent the V5 is in the sellers name, That does mean he's the registered keeper, No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

17 years old and only 50 miles does seem a bit odd, it could well be that the scooter has just been in storage or something but the owner would be eager to tell you this to help prove the extremely low mileage validity.

Does it run perfect? Listen to it, and ride it to find out for yourself. Does it make any strange noises, with 50 miles on the clock it should ride like new after a couple of miles. Don't buy it without knowing.

If you're not sure though or have doubts, just leave it, as those doubts will be in your mind every time you ride it.